# Field NULL Size in memory

Tags: database, memory, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm doing a database with a lot of NULL fields per table (20-25), i'm going to use FoxPro DBMS by the requeriments of the project. I know that is a old software, but i have to use it.
I want to know which is the space that every field NULL use in the memory, thanks.

Comment: No idea. But I do know what to do with whoever came up with those requirements.

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks Will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All data types in Foxpro tables are fixed-width (with the exception of Memo/Blob types).  The amount of space used is the same regardless of whether the field contents are NULL or other data.

Answer (score 1):

FoxPro's `RecSize()` function "returns the size (width) of a table record" as documented in the F1 Help, where apparently the optional Nullable property of a column requires one additional bit, so that with 24 nullable columns you'd get 3 Bytes more per row than zero nullable columns would need.

See also "Visual FoxPro System Capacities" and "Table File Structure (.dbc, .dbf, .frx, .lbx, .mnx, .pjx, .scx, .vcx)" in Help if you are using VFP